# WPF - Saving font to disk, then instantiating GlyphTypeface for font throws exception. Why?

Tags: wpf, fonts, nullreferenceexception

I am mucking about with WPF glyphs and documents and have run into a null reference exception in the .Net 4 framework.

I extract and save true-type fonts to disk as .ttf files, then try to create Glyphs based on the fonts. The first time I save a font to disk and instantiate a GlyphTypeface based on the font *after* creating a GlyphTypeface from another font in the same folder I get a null reference exception.

Say I have fonts A and B. B has not been saved to disk (A may or may not have been saved to disk; that doesn't seem to matter):

1) save B to disk in the same folder as A,
2) create GlyphTypeface using font A,
3) create GlyphTypeface using font B = exception.

```
Null reference exception at:  
at MS.Internal.FontCache.FontFaceLayoutInfo.IntMap.TryGetValue(Int32 key, UInt16& value)  
at MS.Internal.FontCache.FontFaceLayoutInfo..ctor(Font font)  
at System.Windows.Media.GlyphTypeface.Initialize(Uri typefaceSource, StyleSimulations styleSimulations)  
at System.Windows.Media.GlyphTypeface..ctor(Uri typefaceSource)
```

If I restart my app and run it again (with font B already on disk), step 3 doesn't throw an exception.

The code to save a font to disk is simply writing a section from a binary stream and letting go of the file:

```
if (!File.Exists(filename))
{
    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(filename, length))
    {
        fs.Write(m_data, m_index, length);
        fs.Close();
    }
}
```

Any ideas? I don't want to have to put every font in its own folder...

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the workaround of saving each font to its own folder (using the font name for the folder name). The exception went away, so I guess we can chalk this up to a bug in .Net.

Comment: The font-per-folder workaround isn't working for me, did you ever find any more info on this problem?

Comment: Nope, sorry. The workaround is still working for me. I am using .Net 4.0 (and I think it wasn't a problem in .Net 3.5 SP1, but I'm not positive). I check if a font exists in a folder before I create it too; I suspect that if you create a font in its own folder and then try to delete/overwrite it (without restarting your app) it will throw the exception.

Answer (score 3):

This bug has been driving me nuts but I think I have a better understanding of what is going on now.

For testing I used the following XAML:

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Glyphs
    FontUri="C:\Users\Public\Desktop\A.ttf"
    FontRenderingEmSize="100"
    Fill="Black"
    UnicodeString="Test"/>
</Page>
```

Using the [XamlPadX](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2008/08/25/xamlpadx-4-0.aspx) application which runs on the .NET 2 runtime I could reliably render the XAML no matter where I placed the font.

Using the [Kaxaml](http://kaxaml.com/) application which runs on the .NET 4 runtime the XAML would often fail to render depending on where I placed the font in the file system. By moving the font file around and renaming I tried to discover a pattern in what was allowed. However, it was very hard to see a pattern.

For instance storing the font in the path below would render the glyphs:

```
C:\Users\Public\Desktop\A.ttf - OK
```

Renaming it from `A.ttf` to `B.ttf` would throw the exception:

```
C:\Users\Public\Desktop\B.ttf - throws exception
```

Changing the extension would also throw the exception:

```
C:\Users\Public\Desktop\A.odttf - throws exception
```

Renaming parts of the path would sometimes wreak havoc but I was unable to see any pattern. Initially I used the temp path and getting exceptions lead me to this question and the answer about not using that path. However, later I have actually been able to use that path as long as the name of the file is `A.ttf` and not `B.ttf` so avoiding the temp path is not a sure fix.

At some point during my tests using my own WPF application the `B.ttf` file name suddenly started working. However, I had to restart the Kaxaml application before it would accept the `B.ttf` file name. Also, at that point the `A.odttf` file name was still throwing exceptions.

My suggestion is to use an application like Kaxaml or to create a small WPF application to test which font file names are acceptable and then use them. However, I fear that the nature of this bug is such that a "good" font file name may turn "bad" at a later point in time. Only time will show.

Answer (score 1):

I (and a co-worker) finally found what our particular problem was:  do not save the font files to `%TEMP%`.  For some reason, having the fonts saved to some other folder makes it work (for us), and saving it to anywhere inside `%TEMP%` makes it break.

Answer (score 1):

According to [XamlToys Doesn't work on framework 4.0???](http://xamltoys.codeplex.com/discussions/353661/), the problem is in the extension of the file for partial fonts.

When I renamed the .ofttf files I save to .ttf, it all works again. Haven't got the foggiest idea of why that is though. Seems to be new in .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround was to simply replace the < Glyphs > with equavalent < TextBlock >s. The couple of pixels difference in layout was not a problem in my case.

Like you noted was the case for you, in my case also it was not a problem in .Net 3.5, but appeared in .Net 4.0.