# Creating GlyphTypeface object from TTF font stream

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I know how to create a **GlyphTypeface** object using the font file located on the disk by giving absolute path.

```
  GlyphTypeface glyphTypeface = new GlyphTypeface(new Uri(@"C:\SomeTrueTypeFont.ttf", UriKind.Absolute));
```

I am not able to figure out how to create the same **GlyphTypeface** object using font file which is stored in memory stream. My application can't save the font stream to disk due to issues like permission etc.  I appreciate if someone could suggest me about how to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. WPF undercover uses the native [IDWriteFontFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371060.aspx) interface which relies on physical files.

Answer (score 8):

It is possible to create [GlyphTypeface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.glyphtypeface.aspx) from a (copy of a) [Stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx).

It is accomplished in a similar way as is [Packaging Fonts with WPF Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753303%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

You must copy font stream to a [PackagePart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.packagepart.aspx) of an in-memory [Package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.package.aspx) which is added to the [PackageStore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.packagestore.aspx). The crucial part is obtaining the correct [Uri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) which is passed to [GlyphTypeface constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602450.aspx).

Here is one possible implementation of an in-memory package:

```
sealed class MemoryPackage : IDisposable
{
    private static int packageCounter;

    private readonly Uri packageUri = new Uri("payload://memorypackage" + Interlocked.Increment(ref packageCounter), UriKind.Absolute);
    private readonly Package package = Package.Open(new MemoryStream(), FileMode.Create);
    private int partCounter;

    public MemoryPackage()
    {
        PackageStore.AddPackage(this.packageUri, this.package);
    }

    public Uri CreatePart(Stream stream)
    {
        return this.CreatePart(stream, "application/octet-stream");
    }

    public Uri CreatePart(Stream stream, string contentType)
    {
        var partUri = new Uri("/stream" + (++this.partCounter), UriKind.Relative);

        var part = this.package.CreatePart(partUri, contentType);

        using (var partStream = part.GetStream())
            CopyStream(stream, partStream);

        // Each packUri must be globally unique because WPF might perform some caching based on it.
        return PackUriHelper.Create(this.packageUri, partUri);
    }

    public void DeletePart(Uri packUri)
    {
        this.package.DeletePart(PackUriHelper.GetPartUri(packUri));
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        PackageStore.RemovePackage(this.packageUri);
        this.package.Close();
    }

    private static void CopyStream(Stream source, Stream destination)
    {
        const int bufferSize = 4096;

        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        int read;
        while ((read = source.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            destination.Write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

And here is a sample code how to use it to create [GlyphTypeface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.glyphtypeface.aspx) from a (copy of a) [MemoryStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx):

```
GlyphTypeface glyphTypeface;

using (var memoryPackage = new MemoryPackage())
{
    using (var fontStream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "font"))))
    {
        var typefaceSource = memoryPackage.CreatePart(fontStream);

        glyphTypeface = new GlyphTypeface(typefaceSource);

        memoryPackage.DeletePart(typefaceSource);
    }
}

var familyName = glyphTypeface.FamilyNames[CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")];

Console.WriteLine(familyName);
```

Comment: This works AND it actually fixes 2 bugs I saw in GlyphTypeface.  First, it fixes the fact that GlyphTypeface locks the file and leaves a file handle open, preventing the file from being deleted.  Second, it stops a null reference exception (http://stackoverflow.com/q/3075403/88409) from being thrown from the constructor, which would otherwise be thrown when accessing a file (possibly has something to do with file paths).  This solution is amazing, because it completely sidesteps file issues by not using a file at all.