# GlyphTypeface showing error Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, wpf

In a WPF app, I have used the ribbon menu.
Part of XAML is as follows:

```
<DrawingImage>
<DrawingImage.Drawing>
            <GlyphRunDrawing ForegroundBrush="White">
                <GlyphRunDrawing.GlyphRun>
                    <GlyphRun
        CaretStops="{x:Null}" 
        ClusterMap="{x:Null}" 
        IsSideways="False" 
        GlyphOffsets="{x:Null}" 
        GlyphIndices="41 76 79 72" 
        FontRenderingEmSize="18" 
        DeviceFontName="{x:Null}" 
        AdvanceWidths="6.859375 3.90625 3.90625 7.275390625">
                        <GlyphRun.GlyphTypeface>
                            <GlyphTypeface FontUri="C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\SEGOEUI.TTF"/>
                        </GlyphRun.GlyphTypeface>
                    </GlyphRun>
                </GlyphRunDrawing.GlyphRun>
            </GlyphRunDrawing>
</DrawingImage.Drawing>
```

Showing following error while loading the application:

```
at MS.Internal.FontCache.FontFaceLayoutInfo.IntMap.TryGetValue(Int32 key, UInt16& value)
at MS.Internal.FontCache.FontFaceLayoutInfo..ctor(Font font)
at System.Windows.Media.GlyphTypeface.Initialize(Uri typefaceSource, StyleSimulations styleSimulations)
at System.Windows.Media.GlyphTypeface.System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize.EndInit()
at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.InitializationGuard(XamlType xamlType, Object obj, Boolean begin)
at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_EndInit(ObjectWriterContext ctx)
at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.WriteEndObject()
at System.Xaml.XamlWriter.WriteNode(XamlReader reader)
at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.TransformNodes(XamlReader xamlReader, XamlObjectWriter xamlWriter, Boolean onlyLoadOneNode, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Boolean shouldPassLineNumberInfo, IXamlLineInfo xamlLineInfo, IXamlLineInfoConsumer xamlLineInfoConsumer, XamlContextStack`1 stack, IStyleConnector styleConnector)
at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
....
```

Checked the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075403/wpf-saving-font-to-disk-then-instantiating-glyphtypeface-for-font-throws-exce), but in my case just making use of font.

This is intermittent behaviour observed on a particular system.
Not sure why it is failing on particular system

Comment: The Segoe UI Font may not be installed on that system.

Comment: don't think that could be the reason by looking at the code: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Media/GlyphTypeface.cs,140